# Как разметить (аннотировать) объекты в pdf ограничивающими рамками с использованием streamlit

Tags: python, pdf, streamlit

Я хочу открыть в браузере pdf документ и непосредственно в документе или позади него на прозрачном холсте разметить нужные мне объекты ограничивающими рамками.

Если преобразовать pdf страницы в изображения то задача становится простой. Но мне важно, чтобы при разметке текст в pdf был копируемый, а не в виде изображения.

Основная задача это получить координаты ограничивающих рамок, которые будут нанесены поверх pdf документа.

Comment: И что вы по итогу хотите получить?

Comment: Требуется быстро перенести нужный текст из pdf в текстовой файл. Есть pdf файлы в которых часть текста можно перенести просто выделив его (ctrl+c ctrl+v). Но есть проблемный текст при выделении которого захватывается лишние символы и его можно скопировать только маленькими отрывками - что долго. Если бы я мог выделять (ограничить) такой тест рамкой то потом извлечь его по координатам проблем не будет. 

Можно сделать изображение страницы, но тогда не будет возможности работать с хорошо копируемым текстом простой кипипастой

Comment: Так вам нужно только координаты получить? Если да, то через OpenCV вы можете найти все текстовые объекты сделав скриншот открытого пдф, получив потом координаты всех областей с текстом.

Comment: Спасибо за идею, я пробовал и OpenCV и Surya для выявления текстовых строк, документ помимо текста содержит много символов, которые также воспринимаются как строки текста и выделяется много лишнего. Не смог этими инструментами добиться хорошего результата. 

А суть как раз в том, чтобы руками человек мог выделить нужные места с нужными строками текста.

Comment: Можно дополнительно прикрутить тесеракт и все полученные области пытаться распознать, где будете получать пустые строки - просто отфильтруете‍♀️ По итогу останутся только валидные области.